# Why cannot I use "new" to refer a static method in TypeScript？

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript and here's my codes:

```
module MySample {

    export interface IComparable {
        Compare(object1:any,object2:any): number;
    }

    export class MyComparer implements IComparable {
        Compare(object1: any, object2: any): number {
            if (typeof (object1) == "number" && typeof(object2)=="number") {
                var n: number = object1 - object2;
                return n;
            }
            else if (typeof (object1) == "string" && typeof(object2)=="string") {
                return object1 > object2 ? 1 : (object1 == object2) ? 0 : -1;
            }
            throw Error("Cannot compare a different kind of type together!");
        }
    }

    export class GeneralComparer {
        static Comparer(num1:any,num2:any,comparer: IComparable): number {
            return comparer.Compare(num1, num2);
        }
    }
}
```

And now the "compiled codes" are:

```
var MySample;
(function (MySample) {
    var MyComparer = (function () {
        function MyComparer() {
        }
        MyComparer.prototype.Compare = function (object1, object2) {
            if (typeof (object1) == "number" && typeof (object2) == "number") {
                var n = object1 - object2;
                return n;
            } else if (typeof (object1) == "string" && typeof (object2) == "string") {
                return object1 > object2 ? 1 : (object1 == object2) ? 0 : -1;
            }
            throw Error("Cannot compare a different kind of type together!");
        };
        return MyComparer;
    })();
    MySample.MyComparer = MyComparer;

    var GeneralComparer = (function () {
        function GeneralComparer() {
        }
        GeneralComparer.Comparer = function (num1, num2, comparer) {
            return comparer.Compare(num1, num2);
        };
        GeneralComparer.Show = function () {
            return 1;
        };
        return GeneralComparer;
    })();
    MySample.GeneralComparer = GeneralComparer;
})(MySample || (MySample = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

Now I tend to refer the static method as this below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TypeScript HTML App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Ini()
        {
            var result = new MySample.GeneralComparer.Comparer(1, 2, new MySample.MyComparer());
            alert(result);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Ini()">
    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>

    <div id="content">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This ONLY gives me "[object,Object]", why? If I remove "new", everything goes right……Can anyone explain this to me? Many thanks!

Comment: @basarat and Hiệp Lê：Yes, I see But even if I use "new", this will create a new instance and directly call its method instead of returning me [Object,object]……Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you use new, it's to create a new instance of the object.

When you remove "new", it calls the variable MySample to execute the comparison.

```
var MySample;
```

You can try to rename your variable name to "localComparer" for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use the new operator when you want to create a new object. If you are simply calling a function do not use `new`

e.g. :

```
function foo(){
    this.something = 123;
    return 123;
}

var a = foo(); // 123
var b = new foo(); // new object { something: 123 }
```

There is much more to the `new` javascript operator but that should get you started.